# iOS App Rejected due to third-party brand

Tags: ios

I have developed a fashion store app and it uses brand images like Nike, Adidas, Jordan etc. My app has been rejected and I have got this message:

> Your app or its metadata appears to contain potentially misleading
>   content. Specifically, your app includes content that resembles Nike,
>   Adidas, Jordans without the necessary authorization.
>   **Next step:**
>   Please demonstrate your relationship with any third-party brand owners represented in your app.

How am I supposed to do that? Do these brands allow users to reuse logo? Or how do the logo quiz developers get out with this? I mean there are hundreds of Logo Quiz games and every game has more than 100 logos.